# Compare Temp table and Main table to find matches

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables @mtss table:

```
@mtss
( [MM],[YYYY],[month_Start],[month_Finish],[ProjectID],[ProjectedBillable],[ProjectedPayable],[ActualBilled],[ActualPaid],[Total_To_Bill],[Total_To_Pay])

tbl_Snapshot ([MM],[YYYY],[month_Start],[month_Finish],[ProjectID],[ProjectedBillable],[ProjectedPayable],[ActualBilled],[ActualPaid],[Total_To_Bill],[Total_To_Pay]
)
```

I need to compare two tables and find matches

if tbl_snapshot [MM] and [ProjectId] matches then delete record in tbl_snapshot and insert record from @mtts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on 2008, you can use [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to perform the as a single logical operation:

```
;merge into tbl_Snapshot s
using @mtss m on s.MM = m.MM and s.ProjectId = m.ProjectId
when matched then update
set
    YYYY = m.YYYY,
    month_Start = m.month_Start
    /* Other columns as well, not going to type them all out */
;
```

This would also easily extend to other cases you may have to deal with, if the data only exists in one table and not the other, with addition match clauses.

---

Of course, thinking further, in this case a simple `UPDATE` would work also. A `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT` (where the deleted and inserted rows are related by a key) is the equivalent of an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Somethig like:

```
DELETE tbl_snapshot 
FROM tbl_snapshot ss
INNER JOIN @mtss m ON m.MM = ss.MM AND m.ProjectId = ss.ProjectId
```

(I wrote the code directly to this editor so it might have errors, but it should give you an idea how to continue)